# How to ignore and split sql commands based on Go word

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, string, split

I have a script that contains `several SQL Commands`. As I need to split the Commands one by one, I use `go` word to create batch.

```
Dim script = "SELECT * FROM TABLEX; " _
             & "go " _
             & "----- some coment that includes go word like ago " _
             & "INSERT INTO TABLEX .... ;" _
             & "go "
For Each sqlBatch As String In script.Split(New String() {"GO", "Go", "go"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
   'use sqlBatch 
Next
```

If script have comments it works fine, however when it happens to have `go` word like `"ago"` the instruction breaks the string and sql throws error, for instance in the example I would get:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLEX;
----- some coment that includes 
 word like a
INSERT INTO TABLEX .... ;
```

which obviously is not what I want, How can I tell to use `Split` to avoid comments and do not fail on these `go` word containing cases?
So I Get:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLEX;
INSERT INTO TABLEX .... ;
```

Comment: The best way would to be use something "stronger" than the "go" word to split your string.   Like "|go|" ("go" surrounded by pipe characters).

Comment: Do you have any control on how this script is created?

Comment: more less, I could tell that people add or delete some things, however script could be > 100 sentences

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [Sql Server Management objects](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42295) library. The objects in this library are not fooled by the GO separator between commands and you could submit your script using a single ExecuteNonQuery

```
Imports Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common
Imports Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc
Imports Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo
Imports System.Collections.Specialized

' Read the script. It is important to use a StringCollection'
Dim cmd = File.ReadAllText("d:\temp\create.sql")
Dim col = new StringCollection()
col.Add(cmd)

Using con = new SqlConnection(".....")
    Dim svrConnection = new ServerConnection(con)
    Dim server = new Server(svrConnection)
    server.ConnectionContext.ExecuteNonQuery(col)
End Using
```

For this code to work you need to have installed the Sql Server Management Objects libraries and add the required reference and Imports statements

```
Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo.dll
Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll
Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.sfc.dll
```

Comment: The purpose to split script in batch is to execute sentence and then read result, Result could be used in other procedure or written to excel or xml. If I use only one ExecuteNonQuery how could I read all results from all sentences?

Comment: No of course you can't. So perhaps this is not the best approach. But if I remember well there is also something available in those libraries for parsing the script and verify the syntax. I look around if I find something useful.

Comment: [Parser class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.sqlparser.parser.parser(v=sql.120).aspx)

Comment: I give up, cannot find any simple example on how to use this class.

Comment: me neither my friend, However the less is upvote the effort

Answer (score 2):

Finishing using `ScriptSplitter` class from [ststeiger](https://github.com/ststeiger/ScriptSplitter)

```
Dim script = "SELECT * FROM TABLEX; " _
             & Environment.NewLine & "go " _
             & Environment.NewLine & "----- some coment that includes go word like ago " _
             & Environment.NewLine & "INSERT INTO TABLEX .... ;" _
             & Environment.NewLine & "go "
Dim scs As New Subtext.Scripting.ScriptSplitter(script)
For Each str As String In scs
    Console.WriteLine(str)
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Not on my dev machine but I think this would work:

```
    For Each sqlBatch As String In script.Split(New String() 
{environment.newline+"GO", 
environment.newline+"Go", 
environment.newline+"go", 
StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
   'use sqlBatch
```

Comment: it could fail on the case Go is written after a blank space, couldn´t it?

Comment: It didn't look like you had spaces before go's but I think you can just add " go" "go " and " go " to the array since words wouldn't have the space in it, although depending on if there's going to be qualified text or not, you might still want to check for newline